# Why am I getting a delay using IPv6 in ping6, traceroute6, nslookup

Tags: ipv6

I have just switched to an Internet provider offering full dual stack IPv4/6 support, using a Fritzbox 7530 and am experiencing a delay , seemingly in name resolution, when using 'ping6'.

The same configuration is also supporting iOS, windows, linux - and these devices all seem to work fine.

The symptom is:

'ping www.ibm.com' -> instant response, start getting icmp request/response
'ping6 'www.ibm.com' -> About a 3-4s delay after typing the command before the pings start

ie:

```
$ ping6 www.ibm.com                                                                                         
... delay here ...
PING6(56=40+8+8 bytes) 2a02:8010:687f:0:2dbc:1ea2:a301:b111 --> 2a02:26f0:e8:491::b3a
16 bytes from 2a02:26f0:e8:491::b3a, icmp_seq=0 hlim=58 time=11.621 ms
16 bytes from 2a02:26f0:e8:491::b3a, icmp_seq=1 hlim=58 time=10.486 ms
16 bytes from 2a02:26f0:e8:491::b3a, icmp_seq=2 hlim=58 time=11.994 ms
```

The same behaviour is seen for other IPv6 sites such as ipv6.google.com

Using 'nslookup' I also get a delay:

```
... delay actually occurs here
> ipv6.google.com
Server:     192.168.178.1
Address:    192.168.178.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
ipv6.google.com canonical name = ipv6.l.google.com.
>
```

That delay is almost as if it's reverse resolving itself - or a localhost issue?

All the ipv6 testers I've tried in a browser suggest my IPv6 config is fine, sites reachable
I don't notice delays in google chrome
If IPv4 is disabled no delays occur
The router is set to automatic IPv6 (with fast commit)
The macOS Wifi adapter is set to automatic for ipv6 (and dhcp for ipv4)

`scutil --dns` ends with

```
DNS configuration (for scoped queries)

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : fritz.box
  nameserver[0] : 192.168.178.1
  nameserver[1] : fd00::2e91:abff:fe55:2d26
  if_index : 5 (en0)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00020002 (Reachable,Directly Reachable Address)
```

So ipv6 addresses are being requested

`/etc/hosts` has

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
# End of section
192.168.178.48 pi4
```

Any ideas why the delay?

Once past that ipv6 and ipv4 are both working fine it seems (from limited tests so far)

Comment: Is `ping6 2a02:8010:687f:0:2dbc:1ea2:a301:b111` faster or do you get the same delay?

Comment: I still see the same initial delay
Additionally, for this address I don't get ICMP responses

Otherwise ipv6 seems ok though - I notice I am connecting to some sites via ipv6 and not noticing other issues.

But those delays in the tools indicate something is amiss... almost as if it's waiting for something ipv4 related before continuing (as it doesn't occur if I go ipv6 only)

Comment: If you get the same delay with the DNS name *and* with the IP address the delay doesn't seem to be related to your DNS configuration.

Comment: I was wondering if it was reverse resolution, or maybe just trying to connect with ipv4 first (as you say - dns res is fast, with both ipv4 and 6 at least done elsewhere). On linux I might have used strace/dtruss. Maybe try wireshark to see if I can ascertain what is going across the network.

Comment: It turns out just typing 'ping6' is enough to get a delay - before it reminds me of syntax, and 'ping6 banana' (an unknown host) also has the same delay. So it appears to occur regardless.

Given there's no delays in tools like pingplotter, I'm starting to think if it's just a bad utility build

Comment: I tried an alternative tool, fping. Zero delay....

$ fping  -l -s -6 -A www.ibm.com                                                                                              [13:55:54]
2a02:26f0:a1:590::b3a : [0], 64 bytes, 12.9 ms (12.9 avg, 0% loss)
2a02:26f0:a1:590::b3a : [1], 64 bytes, 10.6 ms (11.8 avg, 0% loss)
2a02:26f0:a1:590::b3a : [2], 64 bytes, 10.9 ms (11.5 avg, 0% loss)
2a02:26f0:a1:590::b3a : [3], 64 bytes, 10.4 ms (11.2 avg, 0% loss)
2a02:26f0:a1:590::b3a : [4], 64 bytes, 11.2 ms (11.2 avg, 0% loss)

Comment: ^C
2a02:26f0:a1:590::b3a : xmt/rcv/%loss = 5/5/0%, min/avg/max = 10.4/11.2/12.9

       1 targets
       1 alive
       0 unreachable
       0 unknown addresses

       0 timeouts (waiting for response)
       6 ICMP Echos sent
       5 ICMP Echo Replies received
       0 other ICMP received

 10.4 ms (min round trip time)
 11.2 ms (avg round trip time)
 12.9 ms (max round trip time)
        5.208 sec (elapsed real time)

Comment: If just *typing* ping6 leads to a delay it might be an issue with your shell maybe?

Comment: Re shell - tried bash/zsh , and specifying path to executable directly.... so very odd.. But it does increasing look like it's specific to these extra ipv6 tools, rather than issues with the ipv6 configuration as such....